# Difference between WCF Rest vs WCF vs Web API's and Are Web Service Single Threaded and WCF Multithreaded

Tags: c#, wcf

Does WCF Supports both Single Threading Synchronous And Asynchronous Request and Multithreading Synchronous and Asynchronous Request??

In WCF Architecture it follows Soap Protocol Request Came in Soap Packet Envelope with header , body and Fault Messages (Optional) Request in XML Format And it Returns Data in XML Format Serialize string

In WCF Rest Request Came in as REST Architecture Json /XML Format Body and Http Verbs are Available and Response can go out in any format unlink WCF XML Serialize **if all of the REST API concept are available in WCF Rest then why there is a need of Rest API's**

If Web API's follows full Rest Architecture with Request/Response, Uri's, Versioning, Caching  then in WCF Rest architecture which things are missing
and what are these Full features Purpose in Web API's Http Protocols

Are WCF Multithreaded and Web Service Asmx are Single Threaded ??

Comment: It isn't clear what your question is? Perhaps it is worth noting that WCF is completely deprecated and will not be available in dot net 5.

Comment: The difference between wcf and webapi: https://www.guru99.com/wcf-web-api-difference.html